# Drupal 7 non-www to www

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal-7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have adjusted the .htaccess file in drupal 7 to forward non www to www domains. When I deploy this to AWS elastic beanstalk (with app load balancer) I get lots of 3xx errors for about 50% of the traffic (I have 2 instances).

Any idea why? Any idea how I can solve this or achieve the same redirect in another way?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Comment: When you deployed, can you verify that both instances are running the same code? The 50/50 split would have me think that one instance hasn't updated correctly.

Comment: I had reduced it to one instance, same problem. I found out that the 3xx errors were being caused by the redirection from non www to www in the drupal htaccess file. How do I stop this as it shows as a degraded environment. The redirection works as prescribed though... all requests go to the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **application-load-balancer** for doing the redirection.

Basically: **Console > EC2 > Load-Balancers > Listeners**

Here you can select

- **HTTP : 80** > **View/edit rules**
- **HTTPS : 443** > **View/edit rules**

You can find more information here: [AWS Tutorial on rewriting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html)